# C# good practice waiting for TCP response

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming

While making a c# application for remote controlling cisco routers using TCP, I got the problem of waiting for a response from the router.

For the application I have to connect to a Cisco router using a TCP connection. After the connection has been made a networkstream will push my command to the Cisco router. To let the router process the command, I am using `Thread.Sleep`. This is not the best solution.

Here is the complete code to get a idea what my program is doing.

```
        string IPAddress = "192.168.1.1";
        string message = "show running-config";  // command to run
        int bytes;
        string response = "";

        byte[] responseInBytes = new byte[4096];
        var client = new TcpClient();
        client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress, 23).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        if (client.Connected == true)
        {
            client.ReceiveTimeout = 3;
            client.SendTimeout = 3;
            byte[] messageInBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine();
            stream.Write(messageInBytes, 0, messageInBytes.Count());    //send data to router
            Thread.Sleep(50);                                           // temporary way to let the router fill his tcp response
            bytes = stream.Read(responseInBytes, 0, responseInBytes.Length);
            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseInBytes, 0, bytes);
            return response;                                            //whole command output
        }
        return null;
```

What is a good and reliable way to get the full response.
Thanks for any help or command.

**More info**:

The networksteam is always filled with something, most of the time it is filled with the cisco IOS login page. The biggest problem is to determine when the router is done filling up the response. 
The response I most of the time get:

> "??\u0001??\u0003??\u0018??\u001f\r\n\r\nUser Access Verification\r\n\r\nUsername: "

The return data will be diffent every time because it will be a result of a cisco command. This can vary from a short string to a very long string.

- mrmathijs95 -

Comment: I believe your stream.Read(..) call will block until the data comes available. Have you tried removing the sleep and checking to see if your application still functions properly?

Comment: This can give a direction: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/884583/Advanced-TCP-socket-programming-with-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/884583/Advanced-TCP-socket-programming-with-NET)

Comment: @peggy, `Stream.Read` will block but not 100% sure that you read all data. Use `BinaryReader.Read` which block until expected data will be read

Comment: This might be a little more complete than what Fabio is suggesting : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @peggy by removing the sleep function, the response from the router will be half empty, and will result in only getting the telnet login details.

Comment: TCP is inherently just streams of bytes going in both directions. There's no inherent "messaging" to it, so no built in signal that the other end is "done". You need to define how we (and thus your code) will determine when the other end is done, based purely on the bytes we're receiving. Looking at your example, it may be that it's "we've seen 4 newline sequences and a colon", but that only matches that one example. (More often, for variable length messages, if you can control the protocol details, you'd e.g. arrange for the sender to prepend the message with the message length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading from `NetworkStream` with `Stream.Read` it not 100% sure that you will read all expected data. `Stream.Read` can return when only few packet arrived and not waiting for others.

To be sure that you get all data use `BinaryReader` for reading.
`BinaryReader.Read` method will block current thread until all expected data arrived

```
private string GetResponse(string message)
{
    const int RESPONSE_LENGTH = 4096;
    byte[] messageInBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

    bool leaveStreamOpen = true;
    using(var writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(messageInBytes);
    }

    using(var reader = New BinaryReader(client.GetStream()))
    {
        byte[] bytes = reader.Read(RESPONSE_LENGTH );
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your solution combined with a thread.sleep to let the router process the request. I also used a while loop that checks every X miliseconds if the response has changed( using byte[] comparing) the complete code will be in a answer -

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Thread.Sleep. I would `async/await` the entire thing, given that you don't always know what the data is based on your recent edit. This is how I would do it (untested):

```
public class Program
{
    // call Foo write with "show running-config"
}

public class Foo
{
    private TcpClient _client;
    private ConcurrentQueue<string> _responses;
    private Task _continualRead;
    private CancellationTokenSource _readCancellation;

    public Foo()
    {
        this._responses = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        this._readCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this._continualRead = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.ContinualReadOperation, this._readCancellation.Token, this._readCancellation.Token);

    }

    public async Task<bool> Connect(string ip)
    {
        this._client = new TcpClient
        {
            ReceiveTimeout = 3, // probably shouldn't be 3ms.
            SendTimeout = 3     // ^
        };

        int timeout = 1000;

        return await this.AwaitTimeoutTask(this._client.ConnectAsync(ip, 23), timeout);


    }

    public async void StreamWrite(string message)
    {
        var messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        var stream = this._client.GetStream();
        if (await this.AwaitTimeoutTask(stream.WriteAsync(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length), 1000))
        {
            //write success
        }
        else
        {
            //write failure.
        }

    }

    public async void ContinualReadOperation(object state)
    {
        var token = (CancellationToken)state;
        var stream = this._client.GetStream();
        var byteBuffer = new byte[4096];
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            int bytesLastRead = 0;
            if (stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                bytesLastRead = await stream.ReadAsync(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length, token);
            }

            if (bytesLastRead > 0)
            {
                var response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteBuffer, 0, bytesLastRead);
                this._responses.Enqueue(response);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> AwaitTimeoutTask(Task task, int timeout)
    {
        return await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task;
    }


    public void GetResponses()
    {
        //Do a TryDequeue etc... on this._responses.
    }
}
```

I didn't expose the read cancellation publicly, but you could add this method to cancel the read operation:

```
public void Cancel()
{
    this._readCancellation.Cancel();
}
```

And then dispose of your client and all that fun stuff.

Lastly, because you said there's always data available on the stream, where you're doing the read you may have to do some logic on the number of bytes last read to offset yourself within the stream if the data doesn't clear. You'll know if the responses you're getting is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code for me.
It uses the solution of [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565525/fabio), 
combined with a while loop to check every X miliseconds if the response has changed.

---

```
            client.ReceiveTimeout = 3;
            client.SendTimeout = 3;
            byte[] messageInBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine();
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream(),Encoding.ASCII,true))
            {
                writer.Write(messageInBytes);
            }
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream(),Encoding.ASCII, true))
            {
                while (itIsTheEnd == false)
                {
                    bytes = reader.Read(responseInBytes, 0, responseInBytes.Count());
                    if (lastBytesArray == responseInBytes)
                    {
                        itIsTheEnd = true;
                    }
                    lastBytesArray = responseInBytes;
                    Thread.Sleep(15);
                }
            }
            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseInBytes);
```

---

Thanks for everyone who suggested a solution.
And thanks to [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565525/fabio) for the given solution.

Comment: Why are you sleeping?

Comment: The first sleep ( write sleep ) is optional, and you can remove it. The second sleep is kind of necessary. Some cisco commands will be processing text on the screen for maybe a full second. To be sure the output has fully given by the router. I used a while loop to check if there are changes in the output. if I'm not using the thread.sleep it will check in less than a milisecond and will not detect that the output has changed. This will mostly happend with commands with large output, such as; show running-config. - I removed the thread.sleep in the answer